# ChessBase and Scid vs Pc Annotation

Tags: analysis, software, chessbase, scid, annotation

I am legally blind, but I love to play chess. I like to annotate games. Chess.com does it right in my opinion, but only because the arrows are thick and opaque. I am wondering, is it possible to change the properties of the arrows in ChessBase or Scid vs PC? I thought I could draw in Tarrasch, but honestly, I may be conflating the memory. If you can, then how can I make ChessBase or Scid more like chess.com in terms of opacity?

I love how chess.com draws annotations in an l-shape; it looks so much better. Most of my friends aren't into chess at all, let alone theory, so the illustration is more convenient that way. But I want a local program that allows me to draw more thick, solid arrows. The thickness and opacity are the biggest factors because of my vision. I find it hard to see the origin square when I am drawing longer diagonals in ChessBase because it has that weird translucent tail.

Comment: **I need to correct**. Scid vs. PC version 4.21 can change the arrow width and the length, with two controls in "comment editor".